# Using IBM DOORS and need DXL script to add Paragraph ID to links

Tags: ibm-doors

```cpp
//Hierarchy Builder
/* This script builds an object hierarchy based on an attribute which contains paragraph number(i.e. 3.2.1. etc) */
    #include <Includes/Lib-LibAll.inc>
    pragma runLim, 0
    const string hierAtt = "Obj Number"  // or Object Text
    const string c_Version = "Hierarchy.dxl v1.0"

    Object obj    //what type is Object?
    Object lastO[20] 

    int i
    int reqLen
    int oLevel
    int prevLevel
    int lastReqLen

    string reqNo

    obj  = first current Module
    lastO[ 0 ] = obj
    prevLevel = 0
    lastReqLen = 1 //assume first object has nonzero attr value

//Process objects
    while (!null next obj)
    {  oLevel = 0
       obj = next obj
       reqNo = obj.heirAtt
       reqLen = length( reqNo)
  
    if (reqLen != 0)
      {  
        for i in 0:reqLen-1 do
         if (reqNo[i] == '.')
             oLevel++
             
         if (reqLen > 1 && reqNo[reqLen-2:reqLen-1] == ".0")
          oLevel--

         if (oLevel > prevLevel)
            move(obj, below lastO[oLevel - 1])
         else
            move(obj, after lastO[oLevel] )
        
        lastO[oLevel] = obj
        prevLevel     = oLevel
        lastReqLen    = reqLen
    }
    else
    {
      if (lastReqLen == 0)
      { //move after
       oLevel = prevLevel
       move( obj, after lastO[oLevel] )
      }
      else
     { // move below
       oLevel = previous + 1
       move( obj, after lastO[oLevel -1] )
     }
     
     lastO[ oLevel] = obj
     prevLevel      = oLevel
     lastReqLen     = reqLen
   } // End if reqLen == 0
} //End while (!null next obj)

infoBox "*** Hierarchy Completed ***\n"
```

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. What is a "Paragraph ID" and how is this connected to your script? I see that you want to move objects depending on the content of the attribute "Obj Number", which seems to be an attribute that you filled yourself.

Comment: By Paragraph ID I mean the Object Number. I see your comment below and I do not want to include Headings. I only need the requirements for this module. My code may not be the appropriate code for this. My goal is to get all the links and add an attribute with only the Object Number. There is another Object Identifier but this includes all the children i.e. 2.1.2-02. I do not want that I want only 2.1.2.2 etc.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about your problem. Your question does not contain any question, it's just code without much reference. Pls take a look at [ask] and [mre].

Comment: So, you are talking about the code generated by the analysis wizard which seems to be completely unrelated to the code you provided. When you look at the code you will a line `s = (identifier othero)` or `s = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Object Number", false)`. Do I understand you correctly that you want this output but only the part before the "-"? Please give examples on what you need where

Answer (score 1):

If by "paragraph ID" you mean the number of a "chapter": the mechanism in DOORS is that whenever the attribute "Object Heading" of an object is filled, the Objects number is shown. So, in your script you need to decide whether your original text is a heading or normal text, probably depending on "Obj Number". If the current Object represents a heading, you will probably move the content from "Object Text" to "Object Heading", this:

```
obj."Object Heading" = obj."Object Text" ""
obj."Object Text" = ""
```

see e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq6zJ.png

Comment: Yes, I do not want to include any of the headings. I have my links that I bring in the Object Text with the Object Number with Wizard. I want to remove the Object Text and only leave in the Object Number. I can bring in Object Identifier but I cannot use the nomenclature 2.1.2-02. I need the entire Object Number. I am not linking Headings so I do not need the snippet.

Comment: In order to "remove" lines, either let the analysis wizard run again and don't include Object Text or edit the generated code by removing the corresponding lines.